# How to get the route data resolve value?

Tags: angular, angular4-router

So I have a resolve in my route as follows. It simply resolves user json.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'profile/:id', component: ProfileEditComponent, pathMatch: 'full',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    resolve: {
      user: ProfileResolveService
    }
  },
];
```

My Resolve service is:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProfileResolveService implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(private service: UserService, private router: Router,
    private notificationService: NotificationService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    const id = route.paramMap.get('id');
    return this.service.getUserProfile(id).map((response) => {
      return response;
    }).subscribe(user => user, (error) =>  {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      this.notificationService.error('Oops! Something went wrong.', 3000);
      return null;
    });
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get the resolve in the component and doing the following:

```
 this.activatedRoute.data.map(data => {
    return data.user;
  }).subscribe((res) => {
    console.log('res', res);
  });
```

However, I don't get the value rather I get `{user: Subscriber}` in the log

Comment: may help you out https://medium.com/@dazcyril/resolving-data-in-angular-2-4-and-5-refactoring-components-and-moving-to-ngrx-store-15e15d8be3dd

Answer (score 2):

can you try below like that

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    const id = route.paramMap.get('id') || '';
    return this.service.getUserProfile(id)
       .map((response: any) => {
           return response.data;
        }).catch(Error => {
            this.notificationService.error('Oops! Something went wrong.', 3000);
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return null;
            });
  }
```

in your component

```
var user = this.aroute.snapshot.data['user'];
```

Comment: I get {user: Subscriber} in the log. The resolver sends the user json. I'm not sure what is wrong

Comment: Also it says catch doesnt exist in observable

Comment: can you add your service

Answer (score 0):

it is because you are returning the whole user object in

```
  return data.user;
```

if you want the user value you can use

```
console.log('res', res.user); or res['user']
```

it will print the user value then

Comment: No, res.user is undefined

Comment: If it so then i would suggest you to please put console in  
      this.activatedRoute.data.map(data => { console.log(data)
       return data.user;
    }).subscribe((res) => {
    console.log('res', res);
  });   and verify that you are getting value in data

Comment: Of everything I tried I get {user: Subscriber} in the log. The resolver sends the user json. I'm not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this while handling errors

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    const id = route.paramMap.get('id') || '';
    return this.service.getUserProfile(id).catch((err) =>{
       this.router.navigate(['/login']);
       return Observable.of(null);
     });
}
```

In component do it this way

```
this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((res) => {
    console.log('user', res.user);
});
```

Comment: I get {user: Subscriber} in the log. The resolver sends the user json. I'm not sure what is wrong. – user3840211 just now   edit